# ContentProvider.createUri Cannot resolve method?

Tags: java, android, cursor, uri, adapter

I dont know why i cant compile my code , it is setting me that **ContentProvider.createUri** cannot resolve method. What i am missing can anyone tell me please. Here is my code for class:

```
public class Connectivity extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        MySQLiteHelper db;
        String[] name;
        String[] username;
        String[] password;
        String[] category;
        int[] ids;
        int[] color;
        ListView listView;

        Cursor identityCursor;

        FloatingActionButton addIndentity;
        int REQUEST_CODE =0;

        int color1;

        ToastersAdapter customAdapter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cards_frag, container, false);

            addIndentity = (FloatingActionButton) android.findViewById(R.id.fab3);

            db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());


                  final List<IdentityHelper> list = db.getAllIdentities();


            name= new String[db.getIdentitiesCount()];
            username = new String[db.getIdentitiesCount()];
            password = new String[db.getIdentitiesCount()];
            category = new String[db.getIdentitiesCount()];
            color = new int[db.getIdentitiesCount()];
            ids = new int[db.getIdentitiesCount()];

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                IdentityHelper n= list.get(i);
                name[i]= n.getName();
                username[i]=n.getUsername();
                password[i]=n.getPassword();
                category[i]=n.getCategory();
                color[i] = n.getColor();
                ids[i] = n.getId();

            }

            addIndentity.setOnClickListener(handler);



            // Get access to the underlying writeable database
            SQLiteDatabase dbs = db.getWritableDatabase();
    // Query for items from the database and get a cursor back
            identityCursor = dbs.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM Identities ORDER BY category", null);


            listView = (ListView) android.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


              customAdapter = new ToastersAdapter(getActivity(), identityCursor);
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            addIndentity.attachToListView(listView);
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, Connectivity.this);




            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                        long arg3)
                {



                    ToastersAdapter adapter1 = (ToastersAdapter) adapter.getAdapter();
                    Object sectionObject = adapter1.getItem(position);
                    int cursorPosition = adapter1.getCursorPositionWithoutSections(position);

                    if (adapter1.isSection(position) && sectionObject != null) {
                        // Handle the section being clicked on.
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Header Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (cursorPosition != SectionCursorAdapter.NO_CURSOR_POSITION) {
                        // Handle the cursor item being clicked on.


                                        //Create the bundle
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                    bundle.putString("Name", name[cursorPosition]);
                    bundle.putString("Username",username[cursorPosition]);
                    bundle.putString("Password",password[cursorPosition]);
                    bundle.putString("Category", category[cursorPosition]);
                    bundle.putInt("Color", color[cursorPosition]);
                    bundle.putInt("ID", ids[cursorPosition]);



                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), theIdentity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    Connectivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);
                    getActivity().finish();

                }}
            });



            return android;
        }


        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {


           **String orderBy = category[id] + " ASC, " + name[id] + " ASC";
            return new CursorLoader(this, ContentProvider.createUri(IdentityHelper.class, null), null, null, null, orderBy);**

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

            customAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

            customAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
```

I have used https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter, for Cursor adapter to manipulate the ListView. I will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no `createUri` method in [android.content.ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) class, it appears to me that your `ContentProvider` class is from some other library.
May be it is [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid), which has `createUri` method in `com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider` class.

Comment: No i am not using that, actually i am using https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter @Mussa

Comment: I've looked up SectionCursorAdapter library and found that author in his  [samples](https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/twotoasters/sectioncursoradapter/SectionCursorAdapter.java) is using ActiveAndroid. @Jana

Comment: Look at the imports in this class https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/twotoasters/sectioncursoradaptersample/activity/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know why i cant compile my code , it is setting me that ContentProvider.createUri cannot resolve method

There is no method named `createUri()` [on `ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), whether static or otherwise.